# Unable to display acronyms in LaTeX

Tags: acronyms

So my university gave us a latex format which we had to edit and put our content in it. This page had a list of acronyms but only 3 of them are being displayed on the actual document

[image]

My knowledge of LaTeX is fairly limited so any help is appreciated.

The code for the acronyms is:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\abbreviations
%\begin{acronym}[longest acronym must be entered here]
\begin{acronym}[OKID/ERA]

%\acro{acronym}{in detail}
\acro{AES}{Advanced Encryption Standard}
\acro{P}{Plain Text}
\acro{C}{Cipher Text}
\acro{IP}{Initial Permutation}
\acro{FP}{Final Permutation}
\acro{P2P}{Peer To Peer}
\acro{DES}{Data Encryption Standard}
\acro{XOR}{Exclusive OR}

\end{acronym}
% Use the syntax \ac{acronym} whereever you use this acronym.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy and paste all the code into it. A screenshot is not very helpful (since answerers cannot copy and paste your code to try it out), especially if it doesn't include all the code.

Comment: @Null i actually just figured it out. I'll post it as an answer

Comment: Okay, good. Please edit your question anyway so that it will be more helpful to future visitors who run into the same problem. Welcome to [tex.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured the problem out accidentally. I used `\ac{AES}`in another part of my document and then noticed that it appeared in the abbreviations list. So only the abbreviations that are being used in the document will appear there.

Comment: That's the behavior of the printonlyused option.

Comment: @tucuxi can you explain that in a bit more detail? because i'm fairly new to LaTeX

Comment: \usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} loads the package and passes the option printonlyused to it. (I assume that's what you have in your preamble.) The option does what the name implies. If you don't want that behavior, you can just omit the option. Run "texdoc acronym" to see a better explanation in the package documentation.